# How to password encrypt a pdf in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, encryption

I am currently generating a pdf from html and returning in Base64 using puppeteer but I have tried to add a password security to open it and I have not found how to do it.

I have seen that you can use pdf-lib or pdfKit but I have not succeeded (it seems that these functionalities were removed since the examples I have seen return the error encrypt is not a function and others errors)

I attach the generation code

```
//const pdf = require('html-pdf');
// var { Base64Encode } = require('base64-stream');
// const { PDFDocument, StandardFonts } = require('pdf-lib');
// const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
// const generatorPdf = require('jspdf');
//const base64 = require('base-64');
// require('jspdf-autotable'); 
const { PDFNet } = require('@pdftron/pdfnet-node');

const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
const moment = require('moment'); 

handlebars.registerHelper('formatDate', function (dateString) {
   return new handlebars.SafeString(
       moment(dateString).format("DD/MM/YYYY").toUpperCase()
   );
});
async function middleware(context, res) { 
    let template = context.body.template || context.body.Template;
    const data = context.body.data || context.body.Data;
    let htmlContent = handlebars.compile(template, data)(data);

    const password = context.body.password || context.body.Password;
    return (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setContent(htmlContent);

        const pdf = await page.pdf({
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true 
        }); 
     
        await browser.close();   
       
        let result = { html: Buffer.from(pdf).toString('base64') } 
        res.json(result);
    })();
}

module.exports = middleware;
```

I hope you can give me a guide, thanks

I have looked at several options and using different libraries such as jspdf, pdf-lib, pdfkit, the same puppeteer and I have not succeeded with the examples found on the web

I would like to be able to encrypt the pdf with a custom password and that everything be done in memory since it is thinking for an azure function

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducable code with imports?

Comment: @SamHoque update full code

Comment: @KJ  that It's the idea, sorry if I explained it wrong

Comment: @KJ It is the basic protection, if you want to see it as a false security I agree but it is necessary to give certain control to sensitive data, that is the reason why it is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for someone who will use this is the code

```
const muhammara = require("muhammara");
const { PDFWStreamForBuffer, PDFRStreamForBuffer } = require("muhammara");

function encryptPDF(source, password) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
        let input = new PDFRStreamForBuffer(source);
        let output = new PDFWStreamForBuffer();
        muhammara.recrypt(input, output, {
            password: password,
            userPassword: password,
            ownerPassword: password,
            userProtectionFlag: 4
        });
        resolve(output.buffer);
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }

});
```

}